# nginx userdir without tilde

Tags: nginx, redirect, mod-userdir

Usually userdir's in webservers prefix a `~` to the username, e.g. [https://example.com/~me/](https://example.com/%7Eme/) to access `/home/me/public_html/`.

Now, for $reasons, I need to setup an nginx server that serves directories in `/home/${user}/public_html/` without this `~` prefix: https://example.com/me/.
At the *same time*, the webserver should also serve content from the webroot (`/var/www/html/`).

I don't really care for the case where content is available in both locations (e.g. https://example.com/foo/index.html could be served by both `/var/www/html/foo/index.html` and `/home/foo/public_html/index.html`).

Answers here on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) have lead me to this config:

```
location ~ (?<user>[^/]+)(?<path>.*)?$ {
  alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
  index index.html index.htm;
  autoindex on;
}
```

This works OK, but unfortunately, it also shadows the webroot (so I can no longer access `/var/www/html/index.html` via https://example.com/index.html).

So my 2nd try is this:

```
location ~ (?<user>[^/]+)(?<path>.*)?$ {
  root /home/$user/public_html;
  try_files $path $path/ @fallback;
  index index.html index.htm;
  autoindex on;
}

location @fallback {
  root /var/www/html/;
  index index.html index.htm;
}
```

This allows me to access both `/home/me/public_html/index.html` via https://example.com/me/index.html and `/var/www/html/index.html` via https://example.com/index.html

It also allows me to `/home/me/public_html/bla/index.html` via https://example.com/me/bla/

Unfortunately, things break with https://example.com/me/bla (note the missing trailing slash): nginx will issue a permanent redirect (`301`) to https://example.com/bla/ (stripping away my username! where it really should only do a redirect to https://example.com/me/bla/).
This gives plenty of 404 errors (when `/var/www/html/bla/` does not exist), or the wrong content (when it does exist).

I'm sure people will forget to add their trailing slashes, and then end up in the wrong (or non-existant) directories.

My gut feeling is, that this wrong redirection comes from my use of `root` in the location block.
There's no such problem with `alias`, but how can I use `try_files` with a fallback location in that case?

So: how can I teach nginx to serve userdirs without a `~`, while still serving content from my webroot and allowing the user to forget to type the trailing `/` when they want to access directories on the webserver?

Comment: Did you try linking different doc_roots to differnet domains for example if /home/foo/public_html will serve for domain.com and /var/www/html to another domain like abc.com. You can achieve this by using different configurations for different domain which serves different doc_roots.

Comment: nope, they really should be in the same domain.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `$path/` component in `try_files`?

Comment: probably not, i was following http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files for the base syntax of `try_files` which does suggest a trailing slash

Comment: @TeroKilkanen did a quick check today, and if I want to be able to get the (automatic) index-page of a directory, then I do need the `$path/` component. maybe i misunderstood your comment?

Answer (score 0):

last night i had a stroke of sudden intelligence, and I came up with an improvied regular expression that allows me to combine the `try_files` with the `alias` directive, eliminating the need for the `root` directive.

So here's the final configuration, which appears to do everything i want:

```
    root /var/www/html;
    location ~ (?<user>[^/]+)(?<path>.*/)?(?<file>.*)?$ {
        alias /home/$user/public_html/$path;
        try_files $file $file/ @fallback;

        index index.html index.htm;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location @fallback {
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
    location / {
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
```

i don't really like that i have to duplicate the `location @fallback` to the `location /` block, but i guess i can live with it for now.

as mentioned in my question, this will have `/home/foo/public_html/` override `/var/www/html/foo/`. i wonder whether i can revert this (so that `/var/www/html/foo/` overrides `/home/foo/public_html/`) - but again, that's not high priority.